# On module import, print out helpful statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a module that automatically prints something when loaded. The code would look like this.

```
 from functionList import *



OUTPUT: Hello, here are the available functions in this module created by....
```

If possible I would also like it to be suppressible.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: That message you're printing looks an awful lot like something that should be discovered by reading the module's documentation, not by reading a message that's printed when the module is imported. Really, what's the use case for printing something when the module is imported? This looks like a bad idea to me.

Comment: You can simply put a `print()` call directly in the module body.  But I would recommend against it.  This is generally very poor style.

Comment: Nothing printed out on import is helpful, unless it's a meaningful error message explaining why the import isn't working or correct.

Comment: I work in a research laboratory and we create functions and share them. Sometimes they don't have great documentation in the function. I think it would be helpful to create something like this.

Answer (score 5):

Anything in the global scope will be executed. So if you put `print` with no indentation whatsoever, it will be executed as well. Also on import, that's what `import` really does.

But just because it can be done, it doesn't mean it should. It would be really horrible if suddenly every library decided to print bunch of helpful notes. That's what documentation is for, don't mix those two.

Comment: Hello, I created a file called FunctionList.py that contains this code: print('This is a helpful statement') def functionA(): print ('Hi') def functionB(): print('FunctionB'). When I import FunctionList.py it does not print my statement. The statement was written at the global level in the function. I am not sure what you meant.

Comment: @user9995331 It works for me, it's a bit difficult to debug without knowing exactly what you did. Try asking another question so the code gets properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the code in the module adding a simple `print` at the global level should do what you want.

So for example in functionlist.py:

```
import os

print("Module functionlist has been imported")

def add_function():
    pass
```

If you want it to be suppressible you can replace the print command with a log command from the logging library.

If you wanted to make it suppressible:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
logger.debug("Module functionlist has been imported")

def add_function():
    pass
```

**Please be aware** that since python caches module imports it'll only print the first time its imported each time the script is run.

As others have pointed out, printing while importing a module is considered bad practice, and should be avoided.